# clickonce certificate key (from godaddy/starfield) - password invalid

Tags: wpf, clickonce, code-signing-certificate

I have a WPF application that I'm using clickonce deployment to install from a website.

I purchased a code signing certificate from Godaddy (which is really starfield) following their instructions. This involved (using MMC) creating a code signing request, uploading the request, (...verification on their end...),  downloading the xxx.spc and installing the certificates (3), and exporting the xxx.pfx certificate.

Now when I'm in VS 2015, on the Signing tab for my wpf app, I check the Sign the click once box and Select from File. I select my xxx.pfx file and I'm asked for the password. I enter exactly the same password I entered when I generated the xxx.pfx certificate, but I get an error message box "The password is invalid".

I've scoured the web but have yet to find any similar instances or fixes.

Has anyone else used a Godaddy code signing cert to deploy an app via ClickOnce, and if so how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same issue with a GoDaddy certificate in Visual Studio 2019, same solution. In Firefox, the certificate manager is now under Options; Privacy and Security; Certificates; View Certificates. The GoDaddy instructions for certificate generation and installation have not been updated for Windows 10 (as of October 2019); use other guidance instead.

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution after much hacking about. To recap the issue, following Godaddy's instructions and using MMC to generate the xxx.pfx file resulted in a password invalid error when opening the file in visual studio 2015, to use as the click once code signing certificate.

I resolved this by opening a firefox browser, and went to Tools, Advanced, View Certificates - this opened a certificate manager. I imported my xxx.pfx file, using the password entered when the certificate was exported from MMC. This imported the certificate without a problem. I then used the Backup function to create a new zzz.pfx file, with the same password.

This time importing the zzz.pfx file in Visual Studio 2015 worked without a problem and the password was the exact same one.

I have no idea why the issue occurred but this resolved it. My app is now signed.

(Win 7 home premium, Visual Studio 2015 CE)

Comment: One correction to the above. The certificate 'backed up' from firefox certificate manager is zzz.p12 (not pfx).  In theory there is no difference in the resulting certificate as both formats have been adapted to be identical.

Comment: It's wild that this works, but it was the solution to my problem.  Thanks.